# What if the "which way" detector isn't clearly on or off, just "half on," ie, the device is flakey/unreliable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, double-slit-experiment

If you run the double slit experiment with a "which way" detector, you get different outcomes, depending on whether the device is turned on or turned off. If it's on, you get 2 bands of particles on the back screen. But if it's off, you get many, wave-based interference fringes.

It's usually stated in this either-or fashion. But what if the detector is only "half on," ie, the device is flaky, or is not always reliable, or only works intermittently?

Comment: Although the question is closed, it is worth adding: there are configurations of the double slit in which the amount of which-slit knowledge gained can be varied smoothly between 0% and 100% (and anything in between) without affecting the overall intensity. For photons, this is done with polarization markers. The result of course leads to a corresponding mixture of patterns of no interference and interference. See https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If the detector behind the slits is only on some of the time, then you will see a combination of both patterns at the end of the experiment. That is, you should see an interference pattern (with lower intensity) when the detector was off and a bell-shaped curve distribution when it was on. *The resulting pattern will be a sum of these two.*

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a detector at the slits (initially in the state $|D_0\rangle$), the system will evolve into an entangled state: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\psi_1\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle\right)|D_0\rangle\longrightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\psi_1\rangle|D_1\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle|D_2\rangle\right),$$ where $|D_1\rangle$ and $|D_2\rangle$ are the states of the detector corresponding to detection at slit 1 and slit 2, respectively. The usual either-or scenarios that you describe correspond to either perfect distinguishability between these detector states, $\langle D_1|D_2\rangle=0$, or complete indistinguishability, $|\langle D_1|D_2\rangle|^2=1$. Your scenario is characterized instead by $0<|\langle D_1|D_2\rangle|^2<1$.

To see how this effects the interference pattern, we need the reduced density matrix for the particle, which we get by tracing over the detector states:
\begin{align*}
\hat{\rho}_{\rm part}&={\rm Tr}_{\rm det}(\hat{\rho})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|+|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_2|\langle D_2|D_1\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_1|\langle D_1|D_2\rangle\right).
\end{align*}
The probability density is then
\begin{align*}
\varrho(x)&=\langle x|\hat{\rho}_{\rm part}|x\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|\psi_1(x)|^2+\frac{1}{2}|\psi_2(x)|^2+{\rm Re}\left(\psi_1(x)\psi_2^*(x)\langle D_2|D_1\rangle\right).
\end{align*}
So the interference depends on the overlap between the detector states as ${\rm Re}\left(\psi_1(x)\psi_2^*(x)\langle D_2|D_1\rangle\right)$. For example, if your detector has a 50% reliability, then the interference will be supressed by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.